# Assembler where output file was executable WHILE including the source code

Tags: ms-dos, assembly, cp-m, identify-this-software

I seem to remember using an assembler with the following interesting workflow:  You'd write an assembly language file and assemble it.  The output *overwrote* your source code by placing the executable code after the source code.  You could *run* it as any other program.  Then you'd load your program into an editor - you'd see your source code at the top and following your `END` statement there'd be arbitrary binary gibberish.  You edit your assembly source, reassemble, and again: your single file would be replaced with a new file that had your assembly source at the front and the assembled binary at the end.

(Obviously there must have been a few bytes of binary gibberish at the front of the file too, after assembly, but I can't say I remember that.)

Can't remember if it was CP/M or DOS.  Or 8080 or what. (I put both `cp-m` and `dos` tags on this Q.)

Ring a bell?

Comment: Interesting. Sure it could be started from regular command line without any helper? And sure it was an otherwise normal ASCII file, except for the added code? While it seems possible to hide additional code behind a closing CTRL-Z, I wouldn't know how the defautlt OS-loader could be made to ignore it. Under CP/M and DOS (COM) one would expect at least a jump around the source text (which in turn must be considerable smaller than 64 KiB), while DOS EXE-files require a binary header to do so. Either would rather collide with the source being unchanged at the start of the file.

Comment: Also, 8080 and 8086 JMP codes lie above 80h, not a printable char - and even less when considering the destination address. Quite curious how that should have worked with a seemingly standard ASCII text file. While I can imagine some hacks, they all would make the text file start different - which of course could be hidden by the build in editor - which in itself might be interesting, as it needs to detect them when reoading - even if manipulated by a third party editor. So yeah, I'd be interested to see what comes up.

Comment: The question I have is, **why?**.  I'd run a mile from a language processor that thought it was ok to **modify the source file** while compiling/assembling it.

Comment: @another-dave - I don't actually remember but I think the author probably considered it an advantage in the floppy disk era.  The really low capacity floppy disk era.  Or maybe it had to do with copying files about - you only needed one.  It was certainly an outlier - I'm pretty sure the idea hasn't been picked up anywhere else!

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of an assembler listing file?  Each line is the destination address, then the encoded instruction, and finally the corresponding source line.  Somewhat similar to what you claim here, except on a line-by-line basis.  However, it is intended as a human-readable version of the assembler output; it is not intended to be edited, nor can it be executed.

Comment: @Raffzahn on 8086 there are however conditional jumps  - you can always use jz ... jnz... in tandem. And the semicolon is 3B which is a harmless cmp, and anything following on the first line is restricted only by not including a newline (or perhaps bytes <20h)

Comment: Well, yet again, BBC Basic for the Acorn is an example of that (probably not the one you're asking for): Holds both Assembly source code **and** is an executable program. Admittedly, the binary is built on the fly at run-time.

Comment: @RadovanGarabík While the on an 8086 th J* group is at 7x, any parameter would have to be at least 20h (as you mention) which translates to a file size of at least 8 KiB ... not really likely for something that early.

Comment: The conditional jumps of the 8086 in the 7xh range are all short jumps with displacement -128..127 though. So they cannot jump over any significant distance.

Comment: @ecm ...though I suppose that could still be useful if you use a chain of them inside code comments in the human-readable portion.

Comment: @DrSheldon - definitely not thinking of the listing output of the assembler - this (what I'm remembering) is the source+machine language binary in same file.

Comment: _"You'd write an assembly language file and assemble it"_ - What editor did you use to write the source code, and how did you assemble it? Can you remember any of the commands or procedures involved?

Comment: @BruceAbbott - I have no idea!  I used a lot of random stuff in those days.  You know, you'd go to the "computer store" and there'd be this pegboard on the wall with lots of baggies hanging down - each one had a slip or two of paper - the 'instruction manual' - and a floppy.  That's for the software I bought.  Who knows what I downloaded from BBSes.  (This should all sound familiar to anyone haunting this stack.) (At work of course I used whatever we got from DEC or DG ...)

Comment: @another-dave in Go world it is common enough to include `go-fmt` command in the build script, which doesn't compile the program into the same file as the source code, but it does re-format your source code. Loads of people seem to like Go, and true enough, it has some neat features. But I admit this `go-fmt` business is my pet peeve with that language, combine with some of its (only) formatting choices.

Comment: Right. I can lay out code the way I want it, thanks very much. Sometimes I have to point out to younger programmers that fixing "bug X" does not necessitate running the entire file through their IDE's meaning-destruction module.

Comment: @moonwalker You're not the only one, judging by the existence of https://github.com/mbenkmann/goformat

Comment: @another-dave that said, people leaving trailing whitespace everywhere is another one of my pet peeves, and my IDE is configured to trim it.

Comment: @ssokolow neat, if I ever feel the need to use Go in any of my personal projects I'll consider using that.

Comment: @moonwalker Oh yes. Was one of my very first programs when starting to use size limited micros :)) That and turning tabs into spaces and back when reading/writing source.

Comment: The only code I've seen where code overwrote itself is Data General's bootstrap loader for the Nova and Eclipse. Space was really tight then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing I've *ever* encountered that did something like this was the [`A86` assembler from Eric Isaacson](https://eji.com/a86/).

However, the feature there is that errors from assembling your code would be injected directly into your source file so that you could see them in the place where you needed to *fix* them ("normal" practice at the time being to write a *separate* listing file with hex data, source lines, and errors).

Re-assembling the file would automatically remove these errors before (possibly) adding new errors (or the same error if you forgot to fix something).

What you're discussing still happens nowadays, with (for example) a single file running as a `cmd` script which then runs Python using that exact same script as the source. The trick is to make the Python bits invisible to `cmd` and the `cmd` bits invisible to Python, something like:

```
rem = """
rem cmd stuff goes here, runs python with this file.
rem Python sees this as setting var rem to a multi-line string.
goto :eof
rem """

# Python stuff goes here, cmd will have already left.
```

Or, in your case, "hiding" the executable code from the editor and assembler while still allowing it to run.

A COM file that placed the executable code after the source (in your actual source file) presents a couple of problems, as per below.

---

First, since COM files get loaded at a specific location and run from there (`0x0100`), there would have to be at a minimum some binary jump instruction before the source to go the the executable portion of your code.

A general purpose text editor is likely to complain bitterly about this. I suppose you could have a purpose-built editor which only allowed you to edit the source section (between jump and executable code) but it seems strange to need a special editor for what is really a dubious feature.

Alternatively, you may find a way to encode binary data in such a way that it *looks* like something good to the editor but acts as code when loaded to execute.

If the `;` were used as a comment marker, you could place that at the very start of your file, followed by some executable code and a new-line marker.

For example, ASCII `;` is code point `0x3b` which, on the 8080, was the `DCX SP` instruction for decrementing the starck pointer. Yo could follow that immediately by an equivalent `INX SP` then a jump to your code, something like:

```
0100  3b         DCX  SP     ; First byte of file, but loaded at 0x0100.
0101  33         INX  SP
0102  c3 xx xx   JMP  xxxx
0105  0d 0a      DB   0d, 0a
```

That would show up in your source as `;3<c3><xx><xx><cr><lf>` and your *actual* source code would follow after that.

On the chance that editors would not be keen on characters above code point `0x7f` (such as the `JMP`) or even the non-printable characters *under* `0x80`, I have no doubt that some smart person could construct a byte sequence that did the same job using only printable values (for both opcodes and data).

For example you could load printable-char values into registers and `not` them to get non-printable-char values, or push things on the stack and return rather than jump (unfortunately `RET` is also above `0x7f` but you get the idea).

---

Second, and this is probably *more* important given the 64K-ish limit to COM files, it's probably *not* a good idea to waste in-memory space on storing the source during runtime. It unnecessarily limits the size of your program.

If you have 30K of source, that's 30K *less* space that you have available for your executable code.

Again, you could have a special loader which only pulled out the executable code from the file but then it's not really a COM file at that point.

Comment: you know, I think you've got it! I bet my memory got totally garbled up and that "error messages embedded in the source and then automatically are stripped out the next time" is what I was really thinking of in the warped recesses of my brain!  and the name (`A86`) sounds familiar too ...